# css is not loading even path of css is correct

Tags: css, wordpress

I have written

```
<link media="all" type="text/css"
href="www.nysci.org.php53-14.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/wp-content/themes/nysci/custom.css"
rel="stylesheet">
```

in my header but it is not loading css

can any body please give me a solution?
url is http://www.nysci.org.php53-14.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/

Comment: The URL u provided does not have the css in the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code

**from this**

```
  href="www.nysci.org.php53-14.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/wp-content/themes/nysci/custom.css"
```

**to**

```
 href="http://www.nysci.org.php53-14.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/wp-content/themes/nysci/custom.css"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to `www.nysci.org.php53-14.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/wp-content/themes/nysci/custom.css`, because in your given URL it it takes `http://www.nysci.org.php53-14.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/www.nysci.org.php53-14.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/wp-content/themes/nysci/custom.css`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your CSS file is getting a `404` HTTP error. So you need to change the link from

```
href="www.nysci.org.php53-14.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/wp-content/
themes/nysci/custom.css"
```

to this:

```
href="//www.nysci.org.php53-14.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/wp-content/
themes/nysci/custom.css"
```

When you have the initial link, you will see that the resource file is empty. But once you add `//` and then open the file, you will see the styling tech in the Inspector's Style tab.